# StackOverflowError when opening XML file in eclipce

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, stack-overflow

Hi when iam working with my android app in eclipce and when i opening a XML file in the layout filder i get this error message

```
edit_layout.xml: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

And now i can even open those layouts that i could open yesterday, please help me :(

Comment: can you show the content of your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it i used ActionbarSherlock so the layout preview used this the to preview the layout

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar.ForceOverflow"
```

so to fixed it i just change it to another theme in the original android :)

Answer (score 1):

do you use your own customized view? if so, try to remove it and see if it stops . if it stops , try to check if inside the customized view you've done some logic that cannot be run during editor's time .

please show us the xml file content so we can tell you what could be the cause of it.